# How to Post a request to RCSB API

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to post an API request to the RCSB alignment endpoint following the guidelines at https://alignment.rcsb.org/#pairwise-structure-alignment.  The document gives an example of submitting the request without binary data files that looks like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
    " https://alignment.rcsb.org/api/v1-beta/structures/submit",
    json={
  "context": {
    "mode": "pairwise",
    "method": "FATCAT-rigid",
    "structures": [
      {
        "entry_id": "5KCI",
        "asym_id": "A"
      },
      {
        "entry_id": "5KCI",
        "asym_id": "A"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

I have tried to incorporate it into a response.post call but have been unsuccessful despite restructuring the syntax multiple ways.  #1 How can I get this to work?

#2 The document says that I can also provide binary data files with the request using the 'files' part of the query.  How can I incorporate that into the post request?  My binary files are too big to post here but below is what I have on writing the post:

```
import requests
    
response = requests.post(
    " https://alignment.rcsb.org/api/v1-beta/structures/submit",
    json={
          "context": {
            "mode": "pairwise",
            "method": "FATCAT-rigid",
            "structures": [
              {
                "entry_id": "5KCI",
                "asym_id": "A"
              },
              {
                "entry_id": "5KCI",
                "asym_id": "A"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
    "files":struc1bin,
    struc2bin)
```